# Is a courtyard for ma'aser also obligated in mezuza?

Tags: mezuzah, maaser-tithes, home-house, masechet-maasrot

There are some similarities between the laws of a house that obligates produce in ma'aser, and a house that is obligated to have a mezuza. Produce becomes obligated in ma'aser once it enters a house. This is derived from a verse that mentions ma'aser in connection with the word for "house." A second opinion says that entering a courtyard also makes it obligated from the Torah because of a connection to the word "gate" ([Bava Metsi'a 87b-88a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Bava_Metzia.87b.22?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he)). The obligation of mezuza is also for houses and gates ([Deuteronomy 6:9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Deuteronomy.6.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

[Ma'asrot 3:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.3.7?lang=he) discusses the types of structures that make ma'aser obligated. From [Yoma 10a-b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.10a.13?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), I understand 1) that all of these cases are obligated from the Torah (אלא מעשר מי איכא למימר מדרבנן), and 2) that whether a structure qualifies for this list depends on if it's a "house" (this is implied in the Gemara's explanation for the opinion that it has to serve as a house for both summer and winter).

It seems that in all of the cases in this Mishna of houses obligating ma'aser, there is also an obligation to put up a mezuza according to the respective opinions (Rabbi Yehuda in [Yoma 10a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.10a.16?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), unnamed tanna/Rabbi Me'ir in [Sukka 8b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.8b.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) and Rabbi Yosi in [Mezuza 1:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Tractate_Mezuzah.1.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)).

Given that the definitions for a house seem to be the same between ma'aser and mezuza, does this still hold for courtyards? [Ma'asrot 3:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishnah_Maasrot.3.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he) defines what counts as a courtyard with regard to ma'aser, and gates of courtyards are also obligated in mezuza ([Yoma 11a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.11a.3?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)), but I haven't found the same definitions as those of a courtyard for ma'asrot brought in connection with the laws of mezuza. (If the definitions are different, it would be more understandable according to the opinion that a courtyard doesn't make food obligated in ma'aser from the Torah, but there should still be some logic to having two different definitions.)

So is a courtyard that obligates ma'aser the same kind of courtyard that is obligated in mezuza?